# Scrapy scraping nested text using css selectors

Tags: python, css, scrapy

I have the following html code:

```
<div class='article'>
<p>Lorem <strong>ipsum</strong> si ammet</p>
</div>
```

So to get the text data as: `Lorem ipsum si ammet`, so I tried to use:

```
response.css('div.article >p::text ').extract()
```

But I only receive only `lorem sie ammet`.

**How can I get both `<p>` and `<strong>` texts using CSS selectors?**

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate to me. This question asks for a way specifically using CSS selectors, while the other one only mentions XPath selectors.

Comment: Nope, is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One liner solution.

```
"".join(a.strip() for a in response.css("div.article *::text").extract())
```

`div.article *` means to scrape everything inside the `div.article`

Or an easy way to write it

```
text = ""
for a in response.css("div.article *::text").extract()
    text += a.strip()
```

Both approaches are same,

Answer (score 0):

In Scrapy 2.7+ you can do so with following

```
text = response.css('div.article *::text').getall()
text = [t.strip() for t in text]
text = "".join(text)
```

`getall()` method returns list.